# How to restore Fragments using FragmentTransaction & bottom nav

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, store

In my project I am using bottom navigation view, positioning between 4 fragments via FragmentTransaction class.

Now I'm looking for method that uses Google in Youtube App, when data in fragments are loading when that fragment first called. Next opening same fragment doesn't take as much time as it was before.

How they store data, that were just loaded? Or maybe Google is storing states of these Fragments? (I avoid using ViewPager cause of rendering the data in another Fragments. It's difficult to handle fragment's visibility)

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Comment: i was trying, but using back is not suitable solution for me, tomorrow i'll try the second one

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need anything else :)